# Proton accelarating in homogeneous electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, protons, particle-accelerators

Hi I was studying for my physics exam, when I ran in to this problem.

---

A proton in a particle accelerator uniformly accelerated in 3.23 ms over a distance of 1 km. The field in which the proton is accelerated is homogeneous. The voltage that the proton has passed through is equal to:

A) 1 kV B) 2 kV C) 3 kV  **D) 4 kV**

---

The answer to the question is 4 kV. I struggle however to understand why. I can't find any formulas in my course book combining acceleration and voltage. Does anyone know how to approach this kind of problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For an increase in kinetic energy, a proton would have to move through a negative potential difference

Comment: But the method is to realise that $-qV=1/2mv^2$

Comment: I'm getting 2kV when I tried to do this. Just to clarify the proton started at rest and accelerated over a distance of 1 km in 3.23 milliseconds correct?

Comment: @AfterShave Yes they implied that the proton started from rest.  If you could post your calculation I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting 2kV so I might have made a mistake, but here's my working. Start from
$$s=\frac{1}{2}at^2$$ and substitute in
$$a=\frac{eE}{m}\\E=\frac{V}{s}$$ gives you
$$V = \frac{2 m s^2}{et^2}\approx2~\mathrm{kV}.$$

Again if I've made a mistake someone please point it out.

Comment: Why do I always see the formula V=ED? I know that it would obviously come from V= $\int_{A}^{B} \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dl}$.But that isn't the correct definition of potential? That is -V.

Comment: You can add the sign in if you want but it just gets cancelled by the sign on the charge. In problems like this where directions don't matter I like to just forget about the signs.

Comment: In this problem the charge is positive, so it doesnt cancel out, meaning technically all of the answers OP has said are wrong, including yours.